# Объединение колонок в Pandas DataFrame с применением оператора условия отбора if или аналога

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как в DataFrame создать 3-ю колонку (unit) на основе 2-х колонок (mark1 и mark2) с применением условий отбора? Что-то типа следующей конструкции, но которую можно было бы применить к DataFrame:

```
if mark1.find(u'empty') != -1 and mark2 is not None:
    unit = mark2
else:
    unit = mark1
```

Есть исходный датафрейм:

[image: DataFrame in]

Как получить датафрейм в таком виде?:

[image: DataFrame out]

Comment: Вы можете привести входной DF в виде текста (output of `print(df)`), CSV (output of `print(df.to_csv())`) или словаря (output of `print(df.to_dict())`) - так чтобы мы могли использовать данный текст для создания DF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DF (в будущем всегда приводите ваши входные данные в виде текста, чтобы не приходилось распознавать ваши данные из картинок):

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]:
    mark1  mark2
0   empty   кв.м
1   empty   кв.м
2   empty   кв.м
3    кв.м   кв.м
4    кв.м    NaN
5   empty     шт
6   empty     шт
7   empty     шт
8   empty  empty
9   empty  empty
10  empty    NaN
```

Решение:

```
In [82]: x = df[df.ne('empty')]

In [83]: df['unit'] = x['mark1'].combine_first(x['mark2'])

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
    mark1  mark2  unit
0   empty   кв.м  кв.м
1   empty   кв.м  кв.м
2   empty   кв.м  кв.м
3    кв.м   кв.м  кв.м
4    кв.м    NaN  кв.м
5   empty     шт    шт
6   empty     шт    шт
7   empty     шт    шт
8   empty  empty   NaN
9   empty  empty   NaN
10  empty    NaN   NaN
```

если вы хотите заменить отсутствующие значения (`NaN`) словом (`empty`):

```
In [85]: df['unit'] = x['mark1'].combine_first(x['mark2']).fillna('empty')

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
    mark1  mark2   unit
0   empty   кв.м   кв.м
1   empty   кв.м   кв.м
2   empty   кв.м   кв.м
3    кв.м   кв.м   кв.м
4    кв.м    NaN   кв.м
5   empty     шт     шт
6   empty     шт     шт
7   empty     шт     шт
8   empty  empty  empty
9   empty  empty  empty
10  empty    NaN  empty
```

PS заменять `NaN` не рекомендуют, т.к. вы не сможете использовать [специальные функции для работы с отсутствующими данными](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) и отличать слово `empty` от `NaN` после такой обработки вы тоже не сможете...

Comment: Спасибо, за простую, но мощную конструкцию.

Comment: Спасибо, за простую, но мощную конструкцию, но у меня не получается получить такой же результат. х - это промежуточный датафрейм? Ввел конструкцию с примера (df['unit'] = x['mark1'].combine_first(x['mark2'])).. выдает ошибку: name 'x' is not defined..  Добавил строку x=df. Работает, но тогда в unit пишутся просто данные с mark1. Работаю в Python 2.7

Comment: @Vladimir, да, забыл указать -  `x = df[df.ne('empty')]`. `empty` - это у вас строка или вы таким образом обозначили `NaN` или пустые строки?

Comment: empty - это слово, которое обозначает, что единица размерности не определена, вообщем, это могло быть любое слово... Спасибо. С пояснением по x... все работает.

Answer (score 1):

если у вас в исходном DataFrame `NaN`'s:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   mark1 mark2
0    NaN  кв.м
1    NaN  кв.м
2    NaN  кв.м
3   кв.м  кв.м
4   кв.м   NaN
5    NaN    шт
6    NaN    шт
7    NaN    шт
8    NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN
```

то все еще проще:

```
In [44]: df['unit'] = df['mark1'].combine_first(df['mark2'])

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   mark1 mark2  unit
0    NaN  кв.м  кв.м
1    NaN  кв.м  кв.м
2    NaN  кв.м  кв.м
3   кв.м  кв.м  кв.м
4   кв.м   NaN  кв.м
5    NaN    шт    шт
6    NaN    шт    шт
7    NaN    шт    шт
8    NaN   NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение более длинное, с использованием конструкции if else, ...

Создал функцию:

```
def make_con (c):              # функция для проверки условий в датафрейме
if c['mark1']=='empty': # c['mark1']=='empty' and c['mark2']<>'NaN' не работает
    c=c['mark2']
else:
    c=c['mark1']
return c
```

Поскольку условие c['mark1']=='empty' and c['mark2']<>'NaN' не сработало, пришлось дополнительно строку добавить

```
df['mark2'].fillna('empty', inplace=True) #заменяем значения NaN -> 'empty'
```

Затем применил функцию в конструкции df.apply()

```
df['unit'] = df.apply(make_con, axis=1)
```

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать от экспертов, является ли данное решение эквивалентным к первому ответу-решению? Возможно я не учел какие-то "подводные камни"...По крайней мере результат получился аналогичным Out[86]

Comment: `df.apply(..., axis=1) ` - ужасно медленный, лучше его избегать если есть такая возможность...